# Swift 2 Protocol - Property with a Generic Type?

Tags: swift2

In my project using Swift 2, I am dealing with 2 protocols, `MyViewControllerProtocol` and `MyViewModelProtocol`. I want all View Controllers to conform to `MyViewControllerProtocol`. This protocol will require a property. The property should conform to the `MyViewModel` protocol.

What I was thinking would work here would be something like this:

```
protocol MyViewControllerProtocol {
    var viewModel: <T:MyViewModelProtocol> { get set }
} 

class MyCustomViewModel: MyViewModelProtocol {
     // Implementation here
}
```

Then for the View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyViewControllerProtocol {
    var viewModel: MyCustomViewModel {
        // Getter and Setter implementations here
    }
}
```

I am most likely thinking about this wrong. This will not compile, and I haven't yet seen this type of implementation in conjunction with a property. Is there some other pattern that could accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to have dynamic protocol property type, there's `typealias`.

```
protocol MyViewModel {
  var title: String { get set }
}

protocol MyViewController {
  typealias MyViewModelType

  var viewModel: MyViewModelType { get set }
}

class BaseViewController<T: MyViewModel>: MyViewController {
  typealias MyViewModelType = T
  var viewModel: T

  init(_ viewModel: T) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
}

struct CarViewModel: MyViewModel {
  var title: String = "Car"
}

struct BikeViewModel: MyViewModel {
  var title: String = "Bike"
}

let car = BaseViewController(CarViewModel())
let bike = BaseViewController(BikeViewModel())
```

If you try to use it with model not conforming to your `MyViewModel` protocol, it will not work:

```
struct AnotherModel {
  var title: String = "Another"
}

let another = BaseViewController(AnotherModel())
```

This has some gotchas like you can't pass your view controller via argument of `MyViewController` type, because of `typealias`. This is not going to work:

```
func something(vc: MyViewController) {
}
```

Why not simpler approach without `typealias`. If I understood you correctly, you don't need them. Something like:

```
protocol MyViewModel {
  var title: String { get set }
}

protocol MyViewController {
  var viewModel: MyViewModel { get set }
}

class BaseViewController: MyViewController {
  var viewModel: MyViewModel

  init(_ viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
  }
}

struct CarViewModel: MyViewModel {
  var title: String = "Car"
}

struct BikeViewModel: MyViewModel {
  var title: String = "Bike"
}
```

And now you can use `MyViewController` protocol as a variable type:

```
let bike: MyViewController = BaseViewController(BikeViewModel())
let car: MyViewController = BaseViewController(CarViewModel())
```

You can pass it to some function as `MyViewController`:

```
func something(vc: MyViewController) {
}
```

And you can't do this as well:

```
struct AnotherViewModel {
  var title: String = "Another"
}

let another: MyViewController = BaseViewController(AnotherViewModel())
```

Did I miss something? I mean, about your generics and type constraints? Do you have some use case which forces you to use them?

Answer (score 3):

typealias for protocols has been deprecated and replaced with associatedtype.  The above answers would now be written like:

```
protocol MyViewController { 
    associatedtype MyViewModelType
    var viewModel: MyViewModelType { get set }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Protocols in Swift don't have generic angle brackets. To use generic behavior you have to use `typealias`:

```
protocol MyViewControllerProtocol {
    typealias T: MyViewModelProtocol
    var viewModel: T { get set }
}
```